# SQL error syntax 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a syntax error that I have been trying to fix but I can't figure it out. Error tells that there is a problem near

```
'SET result = CONCAT(result,charac); END IF; SET indexchar = indexchar+1;'
```

Full function I am trying to create:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `alphabet`;
CREATE FUNCTION `alphabet` (serial_number CHAR, name VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE stringalpha VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    DECLARE indexchar int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE charlength INT;
    DECLARE charac CHAR(1);

    SET charlength = CHAR_LENGTH(stringalpha);

WHILE indexchar <= charlength DO
    SET charac = SUBSTRING(stringalpha,indexchar,1);
    IF (serial_number LIKE CONCAT('%',charac,'%') OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',charac,'%'))
        SET result = CONCAT(result,charac);
    END IF;
    SET indexchar = indexchar+1;
END WHILE

RETURN result;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I have tried to write without success:

```
SET result = CONCAT('result','charac');
```

Comment: missing the word `THEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `alphabet`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `alphabet` (serial_number CHAR, name VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE stringalpha VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    DECLARE indexchar int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE charlength INT;
    DECLARE charac CHAR(1);

    SET charlength = CHAR_LENGTH(stringalpha);

WHILE indexchar <= charlength DO
    SET charac = SUBSTRING(stringalpha,indexchar,1);
    IF (serial_number LIKE CONCAT('%',charac,'%') OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',charac,'%')) THEN
        SET result = CONCAT(result,charac);
    END IF;
    SET indexchar = indexchar+1;
END WHILE; -- ********************** missing semi

RETURN result;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

missing `THEN`, missing semi-colon after `END WHILE`, delimiter at the top was on the wrong line