# MySQL Stored Procedure with Auto Increment value

Tags: mysql

My table's primary key 'rfidno' is Auto Increment. and I am trying to form a procedure and it's fairly simple, and it should work. I am geeting error at line 4.

```
SELECT max(rfidno)+1 FROM rfid_uidCREATE PROCEDURE rfidautomatic_INSERT(IN uid varchar(45))
BEGIN
insert into webtest.rfid_uid (rdidno,rfiduid) values (SELECT max(rfidno) + 1 FROM rfid_uid,uid);
END

CREATE PROCEDURE rfidautomatic_INSERT(IN uid varchar(45))
BEGIN
SELECT max(rfidno) + 1 INTO newPK FROM rfid_uid
insert into webtest.rfid_uid (rdidno,rfiduid) values (newPK,uid);
END
```

Comment: missing semi-colon at the end of line 3. Bigger problem is that what you are doing is potentially error prone by use of `MAX()` and concurrency. Much has been written about why not to do that

Comment: I understand your point. I am trying this alternatively, stii error at line 4, there are only 2 columns in table.   CREATE PROCEDURE rfidautomatic_INSERT(IN uid varchar(45))
BEGIN
DECLARE next_id INT;
   SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM webtest.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='rfid_uid');
   SET NEW.field=next_id;
   insert into webtest.rfid_uid (next_id,rfiduid) values (newPK,uid);
END

Comment: Ok you need a DELIMITER wrapper then.

Comment: it's new to me, is there any simple example you know?

Comment: Ex [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40092688) , [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39860634) if you still need help come chat in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room

Comment: it worked for me.